# HP LaserJet 2550 has a carousel motor error

Tags: printer, hp-laserjet

I have a LaserJet 2550, and it's worked pretty good for a long time (except for some slowness a while back, spooling I think), but just recently it suddenly quit working. We moved this summer, but left it at our other place, and just recently when my Dad went over there to try to print something out, it didn't work.

When you turn it on, you hear the fan give a false start (basically a quick pulse), and the carousel goes through its usual thing. Then it starts up in earnest like it's getting ready to print something. All of a sudden it just stops. Everything stops, and the three lower lights are steady. When I push the Go button, the Go light (bottom of the 3) turns off, but the other two stay on.

I looked it up on the HP website and it says it is a carousel motor problem. I called HP, but they said it is out of warranty. I've opened the cover and held the switch with a screw driver so I could watch it, and it goes through its thing like I described (doesn't seem to make a difference whether the imaging drum is in or not), then when it stops it kind of seems to jump back a little bit (the carousel). I hope this all makes sense (I know you like details), and hopefully you also know what to do to fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you're right, I kind of do like details, and one detail I remember someone saying on another forum was that the 2550 was not an easy printer to fix. I'm not a printer tech, so I don't think I'm any help there. My recommendation would be to take it to a recycling plant as the next best option. Sorry this isn't more of an answer, but I thought I should write something.

Comment: Thanks double ;) I'll mark this accepted unless a better one comes along, since you (I) gave that bit about someone saying it was hard to fix. And you (I) recommend to take it to recycling, not trash.